# Link Listbox and sheets in excel for delete - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I create listbox in excel with VBA userform. Its values are obtained from the Sheet in Excel.
How can I delete the values in the sheet "database"  while deleting the box list item?
please help me.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim rng     As Range

Dim MyArray 
Set ws = Sheets("Database")

Set rng = ws.Range("K2:L" & ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

With Me.ListBox1
.Clear
.ColumnHeads = False
.ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count

 MyArray = rng

.List = MyArray

.ColumnWidths = "90;90"
.TopIndex = 0
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
For lItem = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem lItem
        If Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Added two approaches with a concrete solution. Enjoy it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I delete the values in the sheet "database"?**

As you assign database items via the array method (not using `ControlSource`), you want to know how to synchronize listbox items with your data base after manual deletion.

**Approach A) - Write the entire `Listbox1.List`**

If you want a mirror image of the listbox items after the `For`- `Next` loop, you could simply write these items back to a given range (of course you should clear 'surplus rows', too) via the following *one liner*

```
    rng.Resize(Me.ListBox1.ListCount, 2) = Me.ListBox1.List
```

Instead of reduplicating the data range declaration in `CommandButton2_Click`, I'd suggest to declare it ONCE in the declaration head of the Userform code module (and **omit** it in `Userform_Initialize`):

**Thus the complete code would be as follows:**

> ►*Additional notes due to comment*

Insert these two code lines on **top** of your UserForm code module (and **before** any procedures).

`Option Explicit` is strictly recommended in any code to force the declaration of variable types (but you can't use this statement within a `Sub` as you did). The declaration `Dim rng As Range` OUTSIDE the other procedures (i.e. on top) allows that any procedure within this code module *knows* the `rng` variable.

```
Option Explicit               ' declaration head of the UserForm module
Dim rng as Range              ' ONE database declaration only!
                              ' << OUTSIDE of following procedures 
' << Start of regular procedures                              
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws      As Worksheet
' Dim rng   As Range    ' << not needed here, see top declaration
Dim MyArray
Set ws = Sheets("Database")
Set rng = ws.Range("K2:L" & ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count

     MyArray = rng

    .List = MyArray
    .ColumnWidths = "90;90"
    .TopIndex = 0
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()   
Dim lItem&
For lItem = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem lItem           ' remove item from listbox
        If Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

rng.Offset(Me.ListBox1.ListCount, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, 2) = "" ' clear rows
rng.Resize(Me.ListBox1.ListCount, 2) = Me.ListBox1.List             ' write list back

End Sub
```

*Note* that no rows are deleted physically, the resulting listbox items in the two target columns `K:L` are shifted up only *(approach B allows to delete entire rows as well)*.

**Approach B) - Help procedure within main loop**

Using the *same* data range declaration in the declaration head of the UserForm ► as shown above (i.e. OUTSIDE the procedures as Subs or Functions), you could use a help procedure `DelData` allowing to distinguish between two principal cases:

- [1] Shift up deleted cells in your database
- [2] Delete the entire row

**Event procedure** `CommandButton2_Click`

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
' Purpose: delete items both from database and listbox
Dim lItem&
For lItem = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        DelData lItem, True     ' [1] True=delete items and shift up
       'DelData lItem, False    ' [2] False=delete entire row

        ListBox1.RemoveItem lItem           ' remove item from listbox
        If Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
           Exit For                ' do it once in single select case
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Help procedure `DelData`**

```
Sub DelData(ByVal indx&, Optional ByVal bShiftUp As Boolean = True)
' Purpose: delete indicated row items in database
' Note:    data set in OP includes header
    If bShiftUp Then    ' [1] bShiftUp = True: delete row items and shift up
       rng.Offset(indx).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count).Delete xlShiftUp
    Else                ' [2] bShiftUp = False: delete entire row of indicated items
       rng.Offset(indx).Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

**Side note**

It's recommended to fully qualify range references to avoid getting data from wrong workbooks, so I'd suggest the following statement in your `UserForm_Initialize` procedure:

`Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")`

Enjoy it :-)

Comment: Hi T.M.!
Thank you for your description. But your codes do not work. For example, Error in the line "rng.Offset (indx) .Resize (1, rng.Columns.Count) .Delete xlShiftUp". Or "Option Explicit". Please send the completed code (not scattered) to understand.

Comment: In order to avoid possible error 91, you have only to remove or outcomment the declaration `Dim rng As Range` in ►**`UserForm_Initialize`** as *now* it should be defined in the declaration head of your userform module as mentioned: @FirstLast

Comment: Where should I put these two lines below?
[Option Explicit               ' declaration head of the UserForm module]
[Dim rng as Range              ' ONE database declaration only!]

Comment: These are the *very* FIRST two code lines on top of your UserForm code module - @FirstLast

Comment: Please download and test the following link file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/np9ci7rsl4r7fjf/Link%20Listbox%20and%20sheets%20in%20excel%20for%20delete%20-%20VBA.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: It's as I told already - insert these starting code lines `Option Explicit` and `Dim rng As Range` BEFORE your regular procedures on TOP of your UserForm code module and not inside the `UserForm_Initialize` procedure, so the variable `rng` gets known in all UserForm procedures without need to redeclare it again. Then you can run it without problems. C.f. my edit, too. - @FirstLast

Comment: The solution provided by you worked. I really appreciate your guidance. Very accurate. "Good luck".

Answer (score 1):

Before removing the item from the `ListBox` you need to use the located value at the `ListBox.Selected` to find and remove the item from your "database".

Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  For lItem = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Selected(lItem) Then
        DeleteItemFromDatabase ListBox1.Selected(lItem).Value
        ListBox1.RemoveItem lItem
        If Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle Then
          Exit For
        End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Then your `Sub DeleteItemFromDatabase(ByVal itemToDelete As [type])` would find `itemToDelete` in your "database" and remove it.

As an additional note, you may want to consider using Access as your database since it's actually designed to be one. I realize this isn't always possible, but thought I'd throw it out there as a thought for you.

Comment: Hi FreeMan!
Thank you for the time you left, but the explanation is very general. Thanks for giving friends advice if you add the complete code.